# How to automate NuGet package creation using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, automation, package, nuget, nightly-build

For one of my projects I am using many dependencies in the form of NuGet packages. When I change any of them, I need to recreate the package and deploy it every time. We currently have Jenkins setup as our task runner. I was wondering is there a way to automate the package creation and deployment as a nightly job for example.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new Jenkins job and add a windows batch step.
There you can use the following command:

```
C:\J\Nuget\NuGet_2.81.exe pack “%WORKSPACE%\PhantomTube\PhantomTube.Core\PhantomTube.Core.csproj” –IncludeReferencedProjects  –Version %MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%PatchVersion%%PrereleaseString% -Properties Configuration=Release
```

You can add some of the parameters as JOB's variables.

You can find more detailed tutorial here: http://automatetheplanet.com/create-jenkins-job-creating-nuget-packages/

Comment: This works if you are not using an actual nuget server.

Answer (score 3):

I have already Automated Nuget package Creation using Jenkins :
Approach we used was :
Nuget package can be created from either a nuspec file or from project file.
In our case we use Nuspec file for automatic creation of Nuget package.
Strategy we followed was to find all nuspec files in our project directory and pass the nuspec file name to command Nuget pack `<<Your nuspec file name goes here>>`
If you like the approach i can share my command.

code :

```
cls
@echo off

e:

cd << Directory path of your code >>

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


rem automatic Packaging when a nuspec file is found

for /D /r %%A IN (*) do (

cd %%A

if exist *.nuspec (

echo ***************************************************************************************************

echo Located Nuspec file in Path : %%A


for /f %%B IN ('dir /a /b^|findstr /i "nuspec"') do set "res=%%B" & echo Found nuspec file : !res! & echo **************** & echo Packing using nuspec metadata & nuget pack !res!

)

)
```

Comment: Can you share your approach?

Comment: modified my answer with working code , please let me know if you need explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a target to MSBuild and create the nuget automagically. 
http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2014/02/24/nuget-like-a-pro-the-msbuild-way/